# Room generate id with constructor

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am usind Room DB and I have class which I need to generate id:

```
@Entity
data class TaskEntity(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Long?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "start") var startTime: Long?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "duration") var duration: Long?,
): Serializable {

 constructor(
) : this(null, "", 0, 0)
}
```

In the activity I will init the calss and set parameters at runtime:

```
var task: TaskEntity
task = TaskEntity()
task.name = cal.name
....
```

Dao class:

```
@Dao
interface TasksDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM  taskentity ORDER BY startTime ASC")
fun getAllTasks(): List<TaskEntity>

@Insert
fun insert(item: TaskEntity)

@Delete
fun delete(item: TaskEntity)

@Update
fun update(item: TaskEntity)

}
```

But the ID is always null as in the constructor. I have seen in some documentation in case its null it will be auto generated. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your DAO class and how you fill the objects?

Answer (score 1):

You have manually created the `TaskEntity` object, so it's `uid` is null
Also `null` or `0` initial value is allowed for integer field with primary key and `autoGenerate` flag
So i guess it is better to write

```kotlin
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Long,
// ...
) : this(0L, "", 0, 0)
```

Comment: It still not auto generates and always 0

Comment: @Dim Are you using any DAO?